# Combining other widgets into a InputMethodService view

Tags: view, keyboard, widget

I'm trying to create a view for an InputMethodService which displays a Keyboard view as well as other widgets.  In this code I'm trying to display a "hello" TextView just below the keyboard.  I don't see any errors or warnings in the Layout Design tab of the ListKeyboard.xml file, but when the soft keyboard is loaded, I can't see the text.

The code is from the SDK softkeyboard example.  Instead of using input.xml, I create a Relative Layout file in listkeyboard.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/llwrapper"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <com.example.android.softkeyboard.LatinKeyboardView
        android:id="@+id/keyboard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text = "@string/hello"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/keyboard"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the onCreateInputView code:

```
@Override public View onCreateInputView() {

    mListKeyboard = (RelativeLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
            R.layout.listkeyboard, null);
    mInputView = (LatinKeyboardView) 
    mListKeyboard.findViewById(R.id.keyboard);
    mInputView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
    setLatinKeyboard(mQwertyKeyboard);
    return mInputView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been returning the keyboard view alone all this time...  I should have been returning the full view,mListKeyboard, which includes the textView.